# React and on load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a pre-loader in React,

I tried the following

```
class MainApp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.preloader.style.display = 'none';
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div id="loader-container" ref={(c) => { this.preloader = c; }} />
        <SomeComponent />
    );
  }
}
```

However, it seems that the pre-loader disapper long before the load is complete.

How can I bind the removal of the pre-loader to the load event?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I used

```
window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
```

In `componentDidMount`

and

```
  handleLoad() {
    $('#loader-container').hide(); //  $ is available here
  }
```

seems to do the job

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're hiding the loader container when your parent component (MainApp) is mounted and the request probably is not finished yet.

You could pass to the child component a function to call when the load is completed like this:

```
class MainApp extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.hideLoader = this.hideLoader.bind(this);
    }

    hideLoader() {
        this.preloader.style.display = 'none';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="loader-container" ref={(c) => { this.preloader = c; }} />
            <SomeComponent onLoaded={this.hideLoader} />
        );
    }
}
```

And in `SomeComponent` you should call `this.props.onLoaded()` when the request is finished. Something like this:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount () {
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState(...);
            this.props.onLoaded();
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey @kakamg0, why are you referring to a http request? In my case, SomeComponent is a constant component.

Comment: Sorry, I thought when you said that the pre-loader disappeared long before the load was complete you were talking about a request. But I see that you already found the solution.